# Passing args to aapt

Tags: android, ant

I'm running ant and added the below to build.xml
but I'm getting:\
build.xml:51: Element type "aapt" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<target name="-package-resources" > 
     <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->     
        <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package" 
                versioncode="${version.code}" 
                debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}" 
                manifest="AndroidManifest.xml" 
                assets="${asset.absolute.dir}" 
                androidjar="${android.jar}" 
                apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}" 
                resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}" 
                resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" /> 
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        </aapt>     
</target>
```

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the  `>` at the end of `resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"`.